# Проблема с граббером инсты в телеграмме

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Хотел сделать бота, скачивающего посты с инсты, и чтобы пользователь мог из телеграмма прервать цикл

Код:

```py
@dp.message_handler(commands=['grab'])
def inst(message: types.Message, call: CallbackQuery):
    code = call.data
    messages_list = {}
    messages_list.clear()
    messages_list["messages"] = str(message.get_args())
    stt = InlineKeyboardButton(callback_data='Yes', text='Да')
    stt = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2).add(stt)
    try:
        profile = instaloader.Profile.from_username(bt.context, messages_list["messages"])
        posts = profile.get_posts()
        message.answer("Прервать граббер?", reply_markup=start)
        for index, post in enumerate(posts, 1):
            bt.download_post(post, target=f"{profile.username}_{index}")
            if code == "Yes":
                break
    except:
        message.reply("Ошибка")
```

Выдает ошибку:

```
    for responses in itertools.chain.from_iterable(await self.process_updates(updates, fast)):
                                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\New\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 235, in process_updates
    return await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\New\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\handler.py", line 117, in notify
    response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\New\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 256, in process_update
    return await self.message_handlers.notify(update.message)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\New\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\handler.py", line 117, in notify
    response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: inst() missing 1 required positional argument: 'call'
```

Comment: Функция inst ожидает два аргумента (message и call),но получает только один поэтому ошибка

В коде обработчика команды grab, не указан call в списке параметров функции. Вероятно, вы пытались использовать call из @dp.message_handler, но он не передается в обработчик команды.

Нужно передать этот параметр или удалить его, если он не нужен